# CSS doubled pixels on random nth elements with border

Tags: html, css, sass

Currently, I try to recreate a pattern similar to a checkered block.
When I have a look in the browser every nth element has doubled pixels:

[image]

To me, it seems this issue occurs randomly on the elements I create.
Has anyone encountered similar problems and knows how to fix this?

I created this with:

```
// css code

.node{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  content: "";
  border : 1px solid #afc3c2;
  margin-right: -1px;
}

<!-- html code -->
<div class="node"></div>
<div class="node"></div>
<div class="node"></div>
<div class="node"></div>
<div class="node"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In both Microsoft Edge and Safari, this issue seems not to be present. Could you tell us what browser you are using?

(working on MacOS Big Sur 11.2.2)

Comment: You are right, Microsoft Edge and Safari working both fine. 
I face the problem only in Chrome. Thanks for the hint!